# How do I make One Class of Objects go in different directions?

Tags: c#

I am trying to make the 6 fish (3 from left side and 3 from the right side) go towards each other.

I am not quite sure how to do it.

This code below makes all of the 6 fish go in circles, I want to use an if statement so when something happens (e.g. something appears on the screen randomly (chicken.leg != null) the fish will stop going in circles and start going towards the object that appeared on the screen.

```cs
public override void Update(ref GameTime pGameTime)
{
    Vector3 tokenPosition = this.PossessedToken.Position;
    tokenPosition.X = tokenPosition.X + xSpeed;
    this.PossessedToken.Position = tokenPosition;
    this.PossessedToken.Orientation = new Vector3(mFacingDirectionX,
                                            this.PossessedToken.Orientation.Y,
                                            this.PossessedToken.Orientation.Z);

    tokenPosition.Y = tokenPosition.Y + ySpeed;
    this.PossessedToken.Position = tokenPosition;
    this.PossessedToken.Orientation = new Vector3(mFacingDirectionX,
                                            this.PossessedToken.Orientation.Y,
                                            this.PossessedToken.Orientation.Z);

    if (tokenPosition.X == -280 || tokenPosition.X == 320)
    {
        xSpeed = 1;
        ySpeed = -1;
    }

    if (tokenPosition.Y == 120 || tokenPosition.Y == -180 || tokenPosition.Y == -30)
    {
        xSpeed = -1;
        ySpeed = 0;
    }

    if (tokenPosition.X == -300 || tokenPosition.X == 300)
    {
        xSpeed = 1;
        ySpeed = 1;
    }

    if (mAquarium.ChickenLeg != null)
    {
        xSpeed = 1;
    }
}
```

I am expecting 3 fish from the left go to the right, and 3 fish from the right go to the left using one class.

Comment: `if (mAquarium.ChickenLeg != null)` - lol

Comment: the "fish" is going back and forth not in circles. Currently they just bounce symmetrically from the boundaries of the tank. If you want them tho "home" on the new object, you need the object 3D coordinates and change the direction to it. you can calculate the speed vector by using (object_vector-fish_vector )*speed_scale.

Comment: btw, I would suggest you to do bound checks not with equals but with less/more. This way , if your speed is larger than one the objects will not "tunnel" trough the wall